# preg_replace with preg_quote except one column

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-quote

I'm trying to make some tricks with [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) used with [preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php).

I have an array of json data object and what I want to

> Replace all values of keys except the value of one key

Below is the basic structure of the input array:

```
$posts = [{"title":"Test owy post avela","subtitle":"test subtitle",   
           "slug":"test owy-post-laravela-4", "created_at":"2014-11-02"}, 
          {...} ]
```

and I need to replace all values of `tes` to `<span>tes</span>` except from `slug` key's value

below is the code where `$posts` is generated

```
$posts = Post::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$s.'%')->orWhere('content', 'LIKE', '%'.$s.'%')->get()->toArray();
foreach($posts as &$elm){
     $elm = array_map(function($i) use($s){
          return preg_replace("/(" . preg_quote($s) . ")/is", "<span style='background: #92CF18;'>$1</span>", $i);
     }, $elm);
}
```

Comment: You need to post your regex returned by `preg_quote`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to apply the change for all rows other than “SLUG”, I think this is what you want:

```
$posts = Post::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$s.'%')->orWhere('content', 'LIKE', '%'.$s.'%')->get()->toArray();
foreach($posts as &$elm) {
    foreach ($elm as $key => $value)    {
        if ($key != 'SLUG') $elm[$key] = preg_replace("/(" . preg_quote($s) . ")/is", "<span style='background: #92CF18;'>$1</span>", $value);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `s` pattern modifier is of no use because there are not `.` metacharacters in the pattern (all potentially included dots will be made literal by `preg_quote()`).

Answer (score 0):

@cragimc answer is completely correct, but you could use [T-Regx library](https://t-regx.com):

```
Pattern::prepare(["(", [$s], ")/is"])
    ->replace("<span style='background: #92CF18;'>$1</span>")
    ->all()
    ->with($value);
```